# Delphi Seattle on Android shows delpoy error during execution when I embed a self written Java library

Tags: java, android, delphi

During compilation I get an Paclient error.
Does anybody know why and how to solve this problem?

This is what I do:

1. I try to embed a Java function to my Delphi program since there
   seems to be no other solution to add a MediabuttonReceiver.
2. I compile a Java code (code given below) successfully using javac
   from the Delphi installation (compilation script snippet given
   below).
3. I add the compiled jar file to my Delphi project as additional library and compile the Delphi program.
4. Compilation is successful, but during Deploy I get the
   following error message (sorry, this is a German Delphi version). If I compile without the Java library the process is successful, so the error seems to be related to my included jar file.

> ```
>  paclient-Befehlszeile
>   c:\program files\embarcadero\studio\17.0\bin\paclient.exe -u8 
>   --aaptpackage="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe,.\Android\Debug\Project1\library,.\Android\Debug\Project1\classes,.\Android\Debug\Project1\res,.\Android\Debug\Project1\assets,.\Android\Debug\Project1\AndroidManifest.xml,C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-22\android.jar,.\Android\Debug\Project1\bin\Project1-unsigned.apk"
>
>
> [PAClient Fehler] "paclient" exited with code 1.
> Misslungen
> ```

---

Since it might help additional information follows:

This is the Java code I try to embed (this is just a first proof of concept test code):

```
package com.embarcadero.Mediabuttonreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        return;
    }
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    // do something
        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
    abortBroadcast();
}
}
```

This is a snippet from the script I use to compile the java code:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin
set ANDROID_PLATFORM="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-22"
"%JAVA_HOME%\javac.exe" -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -verbose -Xlint:deprecation -cp %ANDROID_PLATFORM%\android.jar -d "%PROJ_DIR%" %file%.java
"%JAVA_HOME%\jar.exe" cvf %file%.jar %file%.class
```

Comment: Fwiw, "Deploy error during compilation" those are two different things. You say compilation goes fine, but the error you get is while deploying. Don't get them confused for being the same thing.

Comment: You are right. In fact that error occurs if I try to execute the program from within the IDE. I changed the topic and the text accordingly.

Comment: I have duplicated your scenario using your source file, which I placed in a file called java\com\embarcadero\Mediabuttonreceiver\MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java within the project folder. Then a build batch file in that java folder sets your unspecified "file" environment variable to com\embarcadero\Mediabuttonreceiver\MediaButtonIntentReceiver and successfully builds a .class file and .jar file in the same java\com\embarcadero\Mediabuttonreceiver subfolder. I added the .jar to a dummy mobile project, which successfully compiles, deploys and installs...

Comment: The same paclient cmd gives this:

paclient command line
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\bin\paclient.exe -u8 
  --aaptpackage="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\22.0.1\Aapt.exe,.\Android\Debug\Project2\library,.\Android\Debug\Project2\classes,.\Android\Debug\Project2\res,.\Android\Debug\Project2\assets,.\Android\Debug\Project2\AndroidManifest.xml,C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-22\android.jar,.\Android\Debug\Project2\bin\Project2-unsigned.apk"

Comment: Executive summary: there is nothing obvious wrong, and from what you describe I get a successful deployment. There is either something you are not telling us, or something wrong with the German paclient from Seattle.....
Try running the paclient command line manually in a Command Prompt and see if you get the same results.

Comment: It was a good idea to lauch the paclient command from the commandline. This gives a much better error description. The process fails with the following error message: "E2312 AndroidManifest.xml:33: Tag <service> missing required attribute name."

Comment: I have no idea why the service tag seems to be correct in your scenario and not in mine, but after correcting the name tag it deploys correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the useful comment from blong I found out that I had to add the following information to the AndroidManifest:

```
<service android:name="com.embarcadero.services.test"
         android:exported="false">
</service>
```

which obviously was not added automatically. After this it works.